# this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
```

I have applied this sort of line in order to make the component UI updated everytime. But in some other cases it start to refreshing the page event if it should reuse the route.

How can we overcome this issue?

Actually in my application there are three tabs in left panel. In each tab there are some listings clicking on list items opens the content on right panel. But in one of the listing there is a common UI that is getting open on some list item, but the problem is that when we don't apply above sort of code then the UI is not getting updated. But if we apply the code then the UI is updated everytime we click on other list item. But the problem is that when we apply this code it start to refresh the page everytime we click on other list in different tabs also, that should not be the case.

If we apply this code `this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;` then how can we revert this functionality under this.router?

Comment: The description lacks details on your implementation, but it sounds like you should look at updating url query params. See https://angular.io/api/router/Router#onSameUrlNavigation

Answer (score 6):

To take less risks I'm just reverting it back to what it was once the reload is done:

```
refresh() {
  const prev = this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute;
  const prevOSN = this.router.onSameUrlNavigation;
  this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
  this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';

  this.router.navigate([this.router.url])).then(() => {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = prev;
    this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = prevOSN;
  });
}
```

Comment: Probably even better to use the promise to revert to the previous values.


this.router.navigate([this.router.url]).then(() => {
  this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = prev;
  this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = prevOSN;
});

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and I changed that line for this:

```
  // override the route reuse strategy
  this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
    return false;
  };

  this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
    if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      // trick the Router into believing its last link wasn't previously loaded
      this.router.navigated = false;
      // if you need to scroll back to top, here is the right place
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  });
```

I don't even know if this works well or do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

we can use it like this:- If we use skipLocationChange router resolve won't call again. It will use previous values on reload

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() =>
    this.router.navigate([this.router.url]));
```

If we use replaceUrl - route resolve functions will be called again on reload.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {replaceUrl: true}).then(() =>
    this.router.navigate([this.router.url]));
```

As suggested here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13831#issuecomment-418984942

Comment: [The Angular docs do not suggest that RouteReuseStrategy is deprecated](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy). Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: In Angular v16, when using in web storm ide is suggested that it is depreciated

Comment: @stefan2718 the class is not deprecated, the router property is deprecated

Comment: @serge the router property on which class?

Comment: @stefan2718 it is the `routeReuseStrategy` of the `Router` class that is deprecated.

Comment: You can see that in the official documentation too at https://angular.dev/api/router/Router

The code shows this:
Deprecated:
Configure using providers instead: `{provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: MyStrategy}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private saveRouterStrategyReuseLogic: any;


ngOnInit() {
    // Save logic
    this.saveRouterStrategyReuseLogic = this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute;
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = (future, curr) => { return false; };
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = 
this.saveRouterStrategyReuseLogic;

}
```